# Unable To Set Application Identity Service to Start Automatically

Tags: windows, windows-services, registry, windows-10, applocker

On Windows 10 Enterprise laptops I found the AppIDSvc was stopped and its Startup Type was set to Manual (Trigger start).  When I attempted to change the Startup Type to Automatic via the GUI, it produced the error "Access is denied" even though services.msc from run from an elevated cmd prompt.

The only way to work around this was to edit the registry and changing  Start=2 at HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\AppIDSvc.

I was able to start the service manually. Also I have modified the registry permission to "Full Control". I tried to reinstall Windows from ISO but the problem persists. Unfortunately Microsoft doesn't reply to this problem clearly on [MSDN](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d4f085f6-6b5f-4970-8651-17f417dec6ca/action?threadDisplayName=unable-to-start-application-identity-service-for-applocker-on-windows-10-enterprise&forum=win10itprosecurity) and [Support Forum](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_repair/cannot-change-application-identity-service-to/bd037720-27a6-4eef-b8f0-94e7ad57729f?auth=1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft docs say:
Starting with Windows 10, the Application Identity service is now a protected process. Because of this, you can no longer manually set the service Startup type to Automatic.
They provide a way to start with GPO, although I don't have such setting as they are referring to.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/keep-secure/configure-the-application-identity-service

Answer (score 0):

Try running in an elevated powershell:

sc.exe config appidsvc start= auto

Answer (score 0):

You can using powershell to setup AppID Service

```
Set-Service -Name AppID -Startup Automatic
```

After reboot system, AppIDSvc will start automatic.

If you want to stop AppIdSvc, you can execute

```
Set-Service -Name AppID -Startup Manual
```

After reboot system, AppIDSvc will stopped.

You can use

```
sc config appidsvc start=auto
```

to config AppIdSvc start after reboot.
But you can't use

```
sc config appidsvc start=disabled
```

to stop AppIdSvc.